# Automation Excel add-in registry location

Tags: excel, excel-addins, office-automation

I have just changed my development environment (I installed a new Windows version 10 on a new machine with the Office Suite 2016). I am trying to expose some Excel dlls through an Automation Add-in procedure (call them namespace `Test` and class `XlAddin`, which I implemented in C#). I expect to retrieve these add-ins in Excel by looking at:

`Excel` > `File` > `Options` > `Add-ins` > `Manage 'Excel Add-ins'` > `Go` > `Automation`

and find it listed as `Test.XlAddin` among the various `Automation Servers`. It does not work in my new environment, although I did not amend my COM registration/unregistration code and my installer code.

In my previous environment, the GUID key for `Test.XlAddin` was registered as
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID key}`

In my new environnement, the GUID key for `Test.XlAddin` is registered as
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Test.XlAddin\CLSID\{GUID key}`

Can one see any reason why this could be happening and what is the actual and correct way to register an Excel add-in and whether this change of registry location might be the cause of this add-in's not showing up in the Excel list of automation servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrepancy in registry paths between your old and new environments could be causing the Excel add-in to not show up. The recommended registry path for Excel add-ins using COM automation is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID key}`.

```cs
// C# code snippet to register a COM Excel add-in
using Microsoft.Win32;

public static void RegisterComObject(string clsid, string assemblyPath)
{
    RegistryKey baseKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("CLSID\\" + clsid);
    baseKey.SetValue(null, "Your Add-in Description");
    baseKey.CreateSubKey("InprocServer32").SetValue("CodeBase", assemblyPath);
}
```

Note: Always remember to run as administrator when you're editing the Windows Registry. Make sure to replace `clsid` and `assemblyPath` with your specific GUID and DLL path, respectively.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I realised that, although I was running VS as an Admin and I was the Admin on my Win account, my Win account was not activated and Win prevented me (in a somewhat weird way without sending errors) from making changes to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` registries.

Comment: Glad it worked! I didn't know about Windows activation silent admin errors. Interesting...